# Java: JComboBox addItem function is different from jdk8 and jdk7

Tags: java, swing, java-8, java-7, jcombobox

On JDK-7 the addItem function from JComboBox accepts an Object as parameter but the addItem from JDK-8 accepts only String as parameter.

How can I use it with objects again? I need to insert a entire object, not only his name for example. I need to get all his attributes after the user choses the selected item from combobox

Answer (score 2):

```
JComboBox<Object> myObjectJComboBox = new JComboBox<Object>();
```

Comment: but the JComboBox is being generated automatically from the project interface, I can’t edit the <String> field created by java

Comment: Convert the project interface to Java 8 too.